# html5 video playing twice (audio doubled) with JQuery .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Huge WTF that I thought was a bug hidden in the [semicomplex web app](http://meemoo.org) that I'm making, but I have pared it down to the simplest code possible, and it is still replicable in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, unpredictably but more than 1/2 of the time.

http://jsfiddle.net/cDpV9/7/

```
var v = $("<video id='v' src='http://ia600401.us.archive.org/18/items/ForrestPlaysTaik/forresto-plays-taik-piano-360.webm' autobuffer='auto' preload autoplay controls></video>");
$("#player").append(v);
```

1. Add a video element.
2. Video starts to load and play.
3. Video audio sounds like it is doubled.
4. Pause the visible video, and one audio track continues.
5. Delete the video element; the ghost audio keeps playing.
6. Delete the frame, and the ghost audio stops (though once in Firefox it continued to play after closing the window, and didn't stop until quitting Firefox).

Here is a screen capture to maybe show that I'm not completely crazy: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLYrakKagRY

It doesn't seem to happen when making the element with `.html()` instead of `.append()`, so that's my only clue: http://jsfiddle.net/cDpV9/6/

```
$("#player").html("<video id='v' src='http://ia600401.us.archive.org/18/items/ForrestPlaysTaik/forresto-plays-taik-piano-360.webm' autobuffer='auto' preload autoplay controls></video>");
```

I'm on OS X 10.6.7.

---

I think that I have it. Even just creating the JQuery object without adding it to the page causes the ghost player to play: http://jsfiddle.net/cDpV9/8/

`var v = $("<video id='v' src='http://ia600401.us.archive.org/18/items/ForrestPlaysTaik/forresto-plays-taik-banjo-360.webm' autobuffer='auto' preload autoplay controls></video>");`

For now I can work around this by using `.html()`. I'll report [the issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9174) to JQuery.

Comment: Even I was facing the same issue. Changing to `$().html()`from `$().append()` fixed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe jQuery caches the content of `$()` before appending it to your player div? So there is another instance of the video tag. It could be an error in jQuery. Have you tried this without Jquery/js?

Comment: That seems to be what is happening, but it is strange that all browsers play those cached ```<video>``` elements in the background. Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work for me with an <audio> element. Keep ending up having an audio file playing that I can't control (play/stop) when skipping to a new file.

Answer (score 9):

I would try adding the autoplay attribute **after** you append the video player. This should then instantiate the play function.

That would be something like this:

```
var v = $("<video id='v' src='videofile.webm' autobuffer='auto' preload controls></video>");
$("#player").append(v);
v.attr('autoplay','autoplay');
```

When you create elements in JavaScript i.e. image elements, objects etc, they are loaded instantly and stored in memory as objects. That is why you can preload images before you load a page. It is therefore not a jQuery bug.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#attr-media-autoplay

> When present, the user agent (as described in the algorithm described
>   herein) will automatically begin playback of the media resource as
>   soon as it can do so without stopping.

Comment: I just used a variation of this technique. In my case the desired video-containing element (an iframe with the video as the src) already existed in the page, and I then poked in the `autoplay` attribute (and added `autoplay=1` to the `src` attribute).

Comment: `$('iframe#video).attr('src',videourl+'?autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent').attr('autoplay','autoplay');`

Answer (score 6):

I've got the same problem over here. This seems to be an issue with using the "autoplay" attribute on your video markup.

- Remove the autoplay attribute
- append your video DOMNode to any node
- if you want autoplay behavior, call videodomnode.play() - using jquery this would be `$('video')[0].play()`

Answer (score 1):

You could get the html of `#player` and append the video your self, then add the total with `.html()` like this:

```
var v = $("#player").html() + "<video id='v' src='http://ia600401.us.archive.org/18/items/ForrestPlaysTaik/forresto-plays-taik-piano-360.webm' autobuffer='auto' preload autoplay controls></video>";
$("#player").html(v);
```

It's not as good as the `.append()` function, but if the `.append()` doesn't work, you might be forced to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked best in my case:

```
var v = '<audio hidden name="media"><source src="text.mp3"><\/audio>';
$('#player').append(v);
$("audio")[$('audio').size()-1].play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by loading video after dom loaded:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
  var v = $("<video id='bgvid' loop muted>
              <source src='/blabla.mp4'  type='video/mp4'>
              </source> 
             </video>");
$(".video-container").append(v);
v.attr('autoplay','autoplay');  
});
```