# HTML5 video buffer

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I have a video that I want to show when the user clicks on a button. I add the video code to the page using jQuery `.append()`.

I've set `autoplay` and currently, the video first starts to play with audio only, and then after a while, starts again from the beginning with audio and video.

Is there a way I could prevent this glitch from happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you specify the browser?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 16 on Win7, but I've gotten complaints from other users on other browsers as well.

Comment: if I understand you correctly; 1. the audio starts to play... 2. when the video starts the audio restarts?   can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

I had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927573/html5-video-playing-twice-audio-doubled-with-jquery-append). jQuery is creating your video element and it starts playing (in the background) before it appends it to the page. It doesn't seem to happen when making the element with .html() instead of .append(): http://jsfiddle.net/cDpV9/6/

```
$("#player").html("<video id='v' src='http:...webm' autobuffer='auto' preload autoplay controls />");
```