# How do I stop audio from continuing to play after removing video tag with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video, autoplay

The audio keeps playing when I use the remove function to remove the video. This doesn't happen if I don't include autoplay as an attribute in the video tag. I tried different things and nothing seems to work.

```
//$("#video").pause();
//$("#video").stop();
$("#video").empty();
$("#video").remove();
```

Comment: It works for me (tested in FF + Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/CFMHQ/ , what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using the current Firefox on a PC

Comment: I tried your code, it works fine... wonder if it's because I'm using append?   $("#visual").append("<video id=\"video\" width=\"448\" height=\"252\" controls preload=\"auto\" poster=\"images/nan/nan_poster.jpg\"><source src=\"images/nan/nan_video.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\" /><source src=\"images/nan/nan_video.webm\" type=\"video/webm\" /><source src=\"images/nan/nan_video.ogv\" type=\"video/ogg\" /></video>");

Comment: hmmm, that is interesting. if we add the video to the DOM with jQuery, it does not work. I can't even pause the video with the controls: http://jsfiddle.net/CFMHQ/1/      EDIT: Looks like this is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927573/html5-video-playing-twice-audio-doubled-with-jquery-append

Comment: it also seems to do strange things to the audio - sometimes it echos or the volume changes

Comment: Yes, it's very strange. Take a look at this question, seems to be the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927573/html5-video-playing-twice-audio-doubled-with-jquery-append

Comment: To the musician in me this sounds quite interesting, especially the echos and volume changes. Can you tape it? ;)

Comment: Yep, same exact problem, thanks for the link. I'm using $("video").trigger("play"); instead of autoplay now and it seems to work okay as a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be a little late, but I had the same issue and the above answer didn't worked for me (yes the tag was created by jQuery)

I got it working by using

```
jQuery('#myvideoTag').trigger('pause');
```

Answer (score 1):

firsly try to create "video" tag empty in the html and create "source" tag into javascript code

```
<html>
.
.
<video id="main-video" autoplay=""></video>
.
.
</html>


<script>
   $('#main-video').append('<source type="video/mp4" src="URL.mp4">');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pause` function that you're trying to call (first commented out line) exists on the DOM object, not the jQuery object.

You can get the DOM object through jQuery's `get` function, example: `$('element').get()[0]`.

http://jsfiddle.net/calvintennant/bTmHn/