# Pausing video doesn't stop audio in html5 video tag

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-chrome, html5-video

I'm pausing a video using its `pause()` method.. the problem is that the audio continues playing... I also tried pausing it from the Javascript Console in Firefox... nothing happens. The video is in .ogg format and is not even playing in Chrome (because I think it's not supported).
I hosted the video on Amazon S3 and it is streaming perfectly. I'm creating the  element dynamically, loading its info from a JSON request.
Here is some code:

```
function showVideo() {
        var video = videodata;

        var videobox = $('#videobox').first();
        var videoplayer = document.getElementById('videoplayer');

        if (video.Enabled) {
            if ((videoplayer != null && videoplayer.currentSrc != video.Location) || videoplayer == null) {
                console.log('Creating video elem');
                videobox.empty();
                videobox.append('<video id="videoplayer" preload="auto" src="' +
                  video.Location + '" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" />');
                videobox.show();
            }
        } else {
            if (videoplayer != null) {
                videoplayer.pause();
                console.log('Pausing video...');
            }
            console.log('Deleting video elem');
            videobox.hide();
            videobox.empty();
        }
    }
```

I already posted a similar question before... but now I'm using other browsers, so I thought I have to create a new question.

---

Here is the working code (thanks to the user *heff*!)

```
function showVideo() {
    var video = videodata;

    var videobox = $('#videobox').first();
    var videoplayer = document.getElementById('videoplayer');

    if (video.Enabled) {
        if ((videoplayer.src != video.Location) || videoplayer.src == '') {
            console.log('Playing video: ' + video.Location);
            videoplayer.src = video.Location;
            videoplayer.load();
            videoplayer.play();
            videobox.show();
        }
    } else {
        if (videoplayer.src != '') {
            console.log('Pausing video...');
            videoplayer.pause();
            videoplayer.src = '';
            videobox.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be that showVideo is being called twice some how and creating two copies, one of which keeps playing even after you call pause on the other.

In your code, the videoplayer var won't refer to the video tag you create later with append, it will point to whatever had that id before, which I'm assuming gets removed when you empty the box, but might stick around in memory (and continue to play sound).

Just my best guess, but either way it'd be better to use the video element's API to set the source and other parameters rather than emptying the box and rebuilding the tag.

```
videoplayer.src = video.Location;
videoplayer.autoplay = true;
// etc.
```

Also, 100% isn't a valid value for the width/height attributes. You'll need to use CSS to make the video stretch to fill an area.

Comment: I followed your suggest to not re-create the element every time and it works. But I checked if the method was entering the same if-block twice: nope. I think it's a bug.. btw, I posted the working code, if someone is having the same problem. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue which was resolved with really wonderful coders. Check out this post. It might be of great use. [HTML5 Video Controls do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039259/html5-video-controls-do-not-work/36040300?noredirect=1#comment59736178_36040300)

If you are using html attribute:

```html
<video id="yourvideoID" poster="Pic.jpg" loop autoplay controls width="100%">
<source src="//example.website/InnovoThermometer.mp4" type="video/mp4">        
</video>
```

Remove autoplay.

Then use jquery to use autoplay instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { $("#bigvid3").get(0).play(); });
```

As for the source there are multiple locations:
[html5 video playing twice (audio doubled) with JQuery .append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927573/html5-video-playing-twice-audio-doubled-with-jquery-append)

and

[Auto-play an HTML5 video on Dom Load using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842308/auto-play-an-html5-video-on-dom-load-using-jquery)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Whoever gave me -1 nice work. I fixed my answer to reflect a more complete response. I am simply trying to help.

Comment: Forget -1s, You've edited your post and made it a nice answer. You'll get more +1s as time flows. Haters gonna Hate :)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the edit :) Without it I won't get better at this hehe

Comment: No Problem at all! Add more wonderful answers and you'll be fine. Best of Luck.