# Auto-play an HTML5 video on Dom Load using jQuery

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to play a video as soon as the dom has loaded using jQuery. This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<video id="video" width="420">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

**JS (script.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(#video).play();
});
```

When you dom loads the video does not play, where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

The jQuery selector `$("#video")` returns a jQuery object. Since `play()` is a function of the DOM element, you must get the DOM element with:

```
$("#video").get(0);
```

before using .play() method:

```
$("#video").get(0).play();
```

Edit: You can also use HTML5 selected tags in case jQuery fall back. Note the `autoplay` tag.

```
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"
width="233" height="147" poster="//www.cdn.com//video.png"
preload="auto" title="Video">
    <source src="//www.cdn.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    <source src="//www.cdn.com/video.ogv" type="video/ogv"/>
    <source src="//www.cdn.com/video.webm" type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

Comment: I tried this but get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Updated. You need `""` around your selector.

Answer (score 1):

I know is not jQuery but in standard javascript with html5 you can use:

```
var video = document.getElementById("target_video");
video.autoplay = true;
video.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('video#video').each( (i,e) => e.play() );
```

As [Justin McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15842341/2540235) noted, the `play()` method exists on the [Video DOM Node](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp) itself, so you first have to resolve the jQuery Object to the specific Node. However, his solution will throw an error if the element with `id="video"` does not exist or is not a `video` Node.