# HTML5 Video Controls do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, video

I have done so much research and although some questions/comments do point me in the right direction, I continue to come to a stand still.

Summary: HTML5 video shows controls but they can't be clicked. When you browse over them they disappear. You cannot click pause, play, mute, nothing. Please help me figure out what is happening.

The website is [www.innovo-medical.com](http://innovo-medical.com) (in case you want to see what's happening)

Formalities below:

```css
div.video-background {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*position: fixed;
    top: 96px;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 1180px;
    /*z-index: -1; */
 padding-top:75px;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom:-70px;
}
div.video-background video {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: -2 !important;
}
div.video-background > div {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
div.video-background .circle-overlay {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -590px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
}
div.video-background .ui-video-background {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-background" id="video-background">
        <video loop="loop" autoplay poster="{{ 'Ladyinblue.jpg' | asset_url }}" width="100%" controls="1">
            <source src="{{ 'InnovoThermometer.mp4' | asset_url }}" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="{{ 'InnovoThermometer.webm' | asset_url }}" type="video/webm">
            <source src="{{ 'InnovoThermometer.ogg' | asset_url }}" type="video/ogg">
            <img alt="" src="{{ 'Ladyinblue.jpg' | asset_url }}" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities,   please download the video below">
        </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
$('.container.main.content').css('z-index',-1)
```

I tested it in your webpage and worked.

It is because the div is placed in front of the video and because that the controls are not being <s>displayed</s> *clickable*.

Then if you <s>remove</s> set to `-1` the `z-index` from the div, the video will be *clickable*.

This is one solution, but the right way is to find in the css file where you are setting the z-index value of the div and change it there, instead of adding a script block to *fix* something you could change in the source.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If one answer worked for your problem and you want to accept it, you can check the [green mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/318874).

Comment: This one pretty much solved the problem. due to margin-bottom: -70px. The div was overlapping the controls. I really appreciate your help in matter. Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help me out!

Comment: I also posted a comment to zer00ne. The other person that answered the question and gave me feedback. Perhaps you've seen that problem before?

Comment: @FredJoseph. I'm not sure... but if this is caused by some events, you can solve it by unbinding all events: `$('video').off()` or even `$('video').find('*').addBack().off();`

Comment: It did help me find this, not sure if it would cause the issue:                                 $(document).ready(function(){      
        $('.video-background').hover(
          function(){
              $('.skip-video').stop().show();
          },
          function(){
              $('.skip-video').stop().hide();
          }

Comment: It's finally solved. Basically remove autoplay and use jquery to autoplay the video instead :) Thank you!!

Comment: @FredJoseph. I'm glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 6):

## Update

Although having the `<img>` tag inside the `<video>` tag is wrong, that's not your problem. You have a couple of elements overlapping your video control bar when the screen gets resized to be narrow. Instead of trying to cut the height of the offending elements and risk your layout's stability, just enter the following in your CSS:

```
div.video-background {
    z-index: 99999;
}

**OR**

div.video-background video {
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

---

You have an `<img>` tag inside the `<video>` tag, it needs to be removed:

```
<video loop="loop" autoplay="" poster="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0641/4457/t/3/assets/Ladyinblue.jpg?4954843373998890788" width="100%" controls="">
        <source src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0641/4457/t/3/assets/InnovoThermometer.mp4?4954843373998890788" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0641/4457/t/3/assets/InnovoThermometer.webm?4954843373998890788" type="video/webm">
        <source src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0641/4457/t/3/assets/InnovoThermometer.ogg?4954843373998890788" type="video/ogg">
        <!---REMOVE THIS TAG--<img alt="" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0641/4457/t/3/assets/Ladyinblue.jpg?4954843373998890788" width="640" height="360" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">---REMOVE THIS TAG --->
    </video>
```

Besides the fact that it's invalid within a `<video>` tag it is inhibiting how it handles user interaction. The attribute `[poster]` is already in the `<video>` tag, so you don't need to worry about it not having a still image to display while it's idle.

Comment: Okay I will remove that! Thank you so much for your help. Also. Great absolutely great feedback on how to better handle my css and dealing with overlapping elements! :)

Comment: There is something else I've noticed and while doing research online I realized that someone else had asked the same question but no one was unable to answer it. It appears that when clicking on the video, the audio starts playing, and if you click again the audio plays again...eventually you have countless audios playing one on top of another. I've never seen a bug like this before. I notice it happens on all browsers.

Comment: Interesting, do you have a link? If you don't, that's fine, I'm pretty sure it's easily found given it's common nature.

Comment: The link was provided in the question originally. you can open the website www.innovo-medical.com and just keep clicking on the video. Use any browser. It seems to affect all. Eventually all you hear is audio on top of audio on top of audio.

Comment: Wow, that's whacked. Ok, remove the OGG video, it's not needed. Then trim the end of your Webm and MP4 up to the file extension (e.g.  `src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0641/4457/t/3/assets/InnovoThermometer.mp4"` What's happening is that hash is identical for every video file and the browsers are getting confused because it looks like an extention and in turn the same file so the browsers play them all in succession of the button click.

Comment: I went even further and deleted both .webm and .ogg. The problem persists. This is literally what I have now:                                                          <div class="video-background" id="video-background">
        <video loop="loop" autoplay poster="{{ 'Ladyinblue.jpg' | asset_url }}" width="100%" controls>
            <source src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0641/4457/t/3/assets/InnovoThermometer.mp4" type="video/mp4">        
        </video>

Comment: I thought that would've done it...hmm. Ok, change `loop="loop"` to `loop` then replace the video file with this: `<source src="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid4.mp4" type="video/mp4">` Might as well do this to: `<video poster="http://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vid4.png" loop controls width="100%">`

Comment: Genius! And guess what? because of your suggestion I found the problem! It's autoplay. For some reason having autoplay makes it do that where if you keep clicking the audio continues to play over and over but if you remove autoplay the issue goes away. The bad news is that it wont autoplay (duh lol)

Comment: I will share these posts with the question I found here on stackoverflow that was never answered. Perhaps it will give them insight if the issue was never resolved. Thank you so much for your efforts!

Comment: lol duh, indeed! It's so obvious it would be the last thing remaining after so much elimination. Your welcome, sir and thank you for the challenge.