# A-frame switching template causes sound (video?) to overlap

Tags: video, aframe

#### My actions (edited):

I'm using A-Frame and A-Frame template-component.
I use template-component to load templates from **<**script id="..."**>** tag like in [example](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/template/examples/data/index.html).

I want to change the template on the fly using the el.setAttribute analogically like in this [example](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/template/examples/swapping/components/template-looper.js).

My template contains a **<**sky**>** element with video as a source.
I can load one template and it works like a charm. I can pause, play it, and so on.

The issue appears when I want to switch the template to a new one that is using the same video resource, or load a new one and then return to the first one.

now I have 2 sounds - one without sync to the video.

One video is displayed but a second sound plays in the background. I also can verify that the sound is not coming from the displayed video. I can still play/pause it and its sound plays over the one in the background.

*edited*
I want to be able to modify not only the **<**sky**>** element but also some others, that's why I wanted to use the template-component. Let's also say that I don't know what assets would be finally used and I don't want to use an asset management system to load tens of Mb of videos/objects and others and suspend the user at a loading screen. As stated [here](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/asset-management-system.html):

> The scene won’t render or initialize until the browser fetches (or errors out) all the assets or the asset system reaches the timeout.

To clarify a little bit more my intention but still keeping it simple, I want the user to be able to change the scene by choosing a prefab (assuming 15Mb per video even with 6-7 assets it may almost reach 100Mb), or by uploading one. And I would really like to avoid reloading the page as it is not an elegant solution for the users perspective.

#### My guess:

I think the old video is not disposed of entirely. I tried using the three.js **.dispose()** method on various elements/ materials/ video itself, but with no luck.
I also tried using **<**a-video**>** as a source, and also deleting the elements before switching, but with the same result.

## Questions

- How to properly remove elements loaded by template so that the video is not stored/ cached anywhere?
- Can I somehow set the autoplay="false" or similar to **<**sky**>** video?
- If my approach is entirely wrong, can you point me in the right direction?

---

#### Example:

```js
function switchVideoToFirst() {
  console.log("switching to first");
  document.getElementById("skyVideoTemplate").setAttribute('template', 'src', "#firstVideo");
}

function switchVideoToSecond() {
  console.log('switching to second');
  document.getElementById("skyVideoTemplate").setAttribute('template', 'src', '#secondVideo');
}

function playVideo() {
  document.getElementById("skyVideo").components.material.material.map.image.play();
}

function pauseVideo() {
  document.getElementById("skyVideo").components.material.material.map.image.pause();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nunjucks/2.3.0/nunjucks.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-template-component@3.2.1/dist/aframe-template-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
    <a-scene embedded>
      <a-entity id="skyVideoTemplate" template="src: #"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </div>
  <button onclick="switchVideoToFirst()">switch video to first</button>
  <button onclick="switchVideoToSecond()">switch video to second</button>
  </br>
  </br>
  <button onclick="playVideo()">play</button>
  <button onclick="pauseVideo()">Pause</button>
</body>

<script id="firstVideo" type='text/nunjucks'>
  <a-sky id="skyVideo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm">
  </a-sky>
  <a-box position="-1 1 -1" color="red"></a-box>
</script>

<script id="secondVideo" type='text/nunjucks'>
  <a-sky id="skyVideo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm">
  </a-sky>
  <a-sphere position="-1 1 -1" color="green"></a-sphere>
</script>
```

I know that I have the same video in both templates but this is deliberate to shorten the example. The issue is strictly related to reloading the same template, either by switching to diferent one and back, or by loading a new one with same video resource.

#### how to reproduce my issue:

- press "switch the video to first" to load the first template.
- press "switch video to second" to load the second template.
- **video is gone but the sound is still going.**
- This point may not work but if you wait long enough the second video will load and you will hear 2 sounds. Then the play/pause controlls will only work on one of them.

also I experienced this:

- press "switch the video to first" to load the first template
- pause the video
- press "switch video to second" to load the second template
- it may take a while of white screen
- when the "second" video is loaded the "first" one is still displayed and paused but the new one starts to play its sound from the beginning. Then you should (or not, can't figure this one out) be able to play/pause the "first" video.

---

#### Example 2

After great input from Piotr Adam Milewski i tried the following

- press "switch the video to first" to load the first template
- press "switch video to second" to load the second template

The sound when changing the template is gone, but after the second template is loaded the sound is starting from the beginning but the video is paused.

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent("pausewhenremoved", {
    init: function() {
        this.el.addEventListener('materialvideoloadeddata', evt => {
            this.videoElement = evt.detail.src;
            //this.videoElement.pause();
        });
    },
    remove() {
        // once i'm removed, the video is going down too
        this.videoElement.pause();
    // I also tried removing the video from DOM but this only changed video to blank (sound was still on)
        //this.videoElement.removeAttribute('src');
        //this.videoElement.load();
        //$(this.videoElement).empty().remove();
    }
});

function switchVideoToFirst() {
  console.log("switching to first");
  document.getElementById("skyVideoTemplate").setAttribute('template', 'src', "#firstVideo");
}

function switchVideoToSecond() {
  console.log('switching to second');
  document.getElementById("skyVideoTemplate").setAttribute('template', 'src', '#secondVideo');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nunjucks/2.3.0/nunjucks.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-template-component@3.2.1/dist/aframe-template-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
    <a-scene embedded>
      <a-entity id="skyVideoTemplate" template="src: #"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </div>
  <button onclick="switchVideoToFirst()">switch video to first</button>
  <button onclick="switchVideoToSecond()">switch video to second</button>
</body>

<script id="firstVideo" type='text/nunjucks'>
  <a-sky id="skyVideo" pausewhenremoved src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm">
  </a-sky>
  <a-box position="-1 1 -1" color="red"></a-box>
</script>

<script id="secondVideo" type='text/nunjucks'>
  <a-sky id="skyVideo" pausewhenremoved src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm">
  </a-sky>
  <a-sphere position="-1 1 -1" color="green"></a-sphere>
</script>
```

---

#### A 'kinda' working example

This is my approach to (at least partially) fix this issue.

I created a standard HTML video element to store the video and modify its source instead of leaving it to A-Frame.

You can switch between two templates, and as long as you don't do it too fast, it will render properly (if you try to switch too early, the screen goes black but the sound is working properly).

```js
function switchVideoToFirst(buttonElement) {
  console.log("switching to first");
  
  if(document.getElementById("sky")) {
    document.getElementById("sky").remove();
  }
  
  document.getElementById("skyVideoTemplate").setAttribute('template', 'src', "#firstVideo");
}

function switchVideoToSecond(buttonElement) {
  console.log('switching to second');
  
  if(document.getElementById("sky")) {
    document.getElementById("sky").remove();
  }
  
  document.getElementById("skyVideoTemplate").setAttribute('template', 'src', '#secondVideo');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nunjucks/2.3.0/nunjucks.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-template-component@3.2.1/dist/aframe-template-component.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent("pausewhenremoved", {
      schema: {
        src: {
          type: 'string',
          default: ''
        }
      },
      init: function() {
        this.videoElement = document.getElementById("skyVideoHolder");
        this.videoElement.setAttribute('src', this.data.src);
        this.videoElement.load();
      },
      play() {
        if (this.videoElement) {
          this.videoElement.play();
        }
      },
      pause() {
        if (this.videoElement) {
          this.videoElement.pause();
        }
      },
      remove() {
        // once i'm removed, the video is going down too
        this.videoElement.pause();
      }
    });
  </script>
  <div style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
    <a-scene embedded>
      <video id="skyVideoHolder" src="" loop></video>
      <a-entity id="skyVideoTemplate" template="src: #"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </div>
  <button onclick="switchVideoToFirst(this)">switch video to first</button>
  <button onclick="switchVideoToSecond(this)">switch video to second</button>
</body>

<script id="firstVideo" type='text/nunjucks'>
  <a-sky id="skyVideo" pausewhenremoved="src: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm" src="#skyVideoHolder">
  </a-sky>
  <a-box position="-1 1 -1" color="red"></a-box>
</script>

<script id="secondVideo" type='text/nunjucks'>
  <a-sky id="skyVideo" pausewhenremoved="src: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm" src="#skyVideoHolder">
  </a-sky>
  <a-sphere position="-1 1 -1" color="green"></a-sphere>
</script>
```

---

disclaimer
the 360 video used in the example is from [this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm) and the author is [Jan Ainali](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Ainali)

Comment: linking this as it may be related because A-Frame uses standard html **<**video**>** tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927573/html5-video-playing-twice-audio-doubled-with-jquery-append

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You ran straight into [this](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3615) issue - once `a-frame` creates a `<video>` from an inline URL it kinda forgets about it. It is relevant, because the template component is just adding and [removing](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/blob/master/components/template/index.js#L54) elements.

So a big simplification of the issue would be - a removed videosphere still plays the video:

```js
setTimeout(e => {
  let sky = document.querySelector("a-sky")
  sky.parentNode.removeChild(sky)
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
  <a-sky id="skyVideo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm">
  </a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

---

One way of solving this, could be creating a component, which will grab the loaded video element, and pause / remove it upon the entity removal:

```js
setTimeout(e => {
  let sky = document.querySelector("a-sky")
  sky.parentNode.removeChild(sky)
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      // once the video data is loaded, store the element
      this.el.addEventListener("materialvideoloadeddata", evt => {
        this.videoEl = evt.detail.src;
      })
    },
    remove() {
      // once i'm removed, the video is going down too
      this.videoEl.pause();
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
  <a-sky foo id="skyVideo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm">
  </a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

---

Another way would be using the asset management system - where you have control over the video HTML element :

```js
let video = document.querySelector("#vid");
let sky = document.querySelector("a-sky");

video.addEventListener("play", e => {
  setTimeout(e => {
    video.pause();
    sky.parentNode.removeChild(sky);
  }, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene background="color: #ECECEC">
  <a-assets>
    <video id="vid" autoplay loop="true" preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/f/fb/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm/Hundra_knektars_marsch_p%C3%A5_Forum_Vulgaris.webm.360p.vp9.webm"></video>
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky id="skyVideo" src="#vid"> </a-sky>
</a-scene>
```

---

On the other hand if you want to change / restart the video, and switch a cube to a sphere, I wouldn't use the `template` component, just manage the video HTML element, and change the cube / sphere visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's useful as the Asset Management System would probably fix the sound issue, but I can't mark it as an answer yet because that would not be a suitable fix if you had plenty of assets and loading them could get user stuck on loading screen for a long time. I updated my question

Comment: @PiotrKolecki right, I've updated my answer, let me know if it's better now

Comment: This indeed fixes the sound issue when changing the template to a different one. But if you try to reload the same template back (or a different one with the same video) the sound is still playing from the beginning in the background (while I can still use pause/play on the ? second instance ?). I added another example.

Comment: I will accept your answer as it really helped me find a workaround for this problem